# How to filter AWS Lambda and API Gateway logs in logstash for Elasticsearch service?

Tags: logstash, aws-api-gateway, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have AWS Lambda and API gateway logs in S3 bucket, i have hosted logstash and moving logs form s3 to elasticsearch service for centralise logging. I want to filter logs of Lambda and api gateway in logstash, so in elastic search i can find things easly.

below is apigateway log that i am getting in kibana "message" field and want to filter

```
{"messageType":"DATA_MESSAGE",
"owner":"",
"logGroup":"API-Gateway-Execution-Logs/live",
"logStream":"d645920e395fe","subscriptionFilters":["API-Gateway-Execution-Logslive"],
"logEvents":[{"id":"3463","timestamp":1553,"message":"(d7b307ed-4c36-11e9) Extended Request Id: W6ghjgj"}]
}

filter i tried with
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:wd}" }
    }
    json{
        source => "wd"
        target => "js"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "t1" => "%{[js][logEvents][message]}"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use Grok in your Logstash configuration file.

Grok is a great way to parse unstructured log data into something structured and queryable.

Use these links to construct your log parser

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

[Example](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-filter-only-error-from-log-file/88591)

Answer (score 1):

i have parsed using json,split and used value using mutate
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    split {
        field => "logEvents"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => ["time", "%{[logEvents][timestamp]}"]
    }
```